# Localhost email for e2e email test

Tags: rest, email, junit, localhost

I need to test that an email has been received and preferably have the ablity to access the mailbox by a rest api. Im looking for an open source solution that i can install which will give me a local email address then i will get the application to send the email to the address where i can validate that it was received. Any ideas on solutions that can be used for the full end to end testing of emails would be appreciated. I know there are some internet based solutions out there but being a test environment the preference would be for a local solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is [smtp4dev](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev) to emulate received email. It listens port 25 but you can setup another port number.

Alternatively, you can use [papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I will check them out. From your experience is it possible to check the emails from these solutions via an api. Im basically running a junit test and need to vslidate the content of an email